# excel formula If Statement is closed mark as Win or Loss

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, multiple-conditions

I'm looking to add column to mark Win or Loss if statement is closed.

so far i have ...

```
=if(and(C75="Closed",O75>0),"W","L")
```

that formula does work but still counts the row if statement is opened and Mark is as L

```
=IF(OR(C59="Closed",O59>0,O59<0),"W","L")
```

Marks as L when it statement still opened.

```
=IF(AND(C59="Y",O59>0),"W",IF(AND(C59="Y",O59<0),"L"))
```

This one works but if marked as opened mark it as False. Is there a way to remove the False?

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do. It is unclear what you are trying to do.

Comment: Do a separate IF on being closed, than the other IF (nested IF). Your current IF results in FALSE if open and you declared that to be `L`